# meteor template argument value differs between helper and event

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to include a Blaze template with an argument and then use the argument value in an event. The problem is that when I include the template a second time with a different argument I get the argument value from the first instance of the template in events.

Template:

```html
<template name="UploadFormLayoutImage">
    <form class="uploadPanel">
        <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="input-field">
        <label for="input-field">Upload file</label>
    </form>
</template>
```

Include:

```
{> UploadFormLayoutImage layoutArea="area1"}}
{> UploadFormLayoutImage layoutArea="area2"}}
```

js:

```js
Template.UploadFormLayoutImage.onCreated(function(){
   this.currentArea = new ReactiveVar;
   this.currentArea.set(this.data.layoutArea);
});


Template.UploadFormLayoutImage.helpers({
    layoutArea: function() {
        return Template.instance().currentArea.get(); //Returns the correct argument value for each instance of the template.
    }
});


Template.UploadFormLayoutImage.events({
    'change input[type="file"]': function(e, instance) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(instance.data.layoutArea); //Allways returns 'area1'
    }
});
```

What am I missing here? (This is my first Stackoverflow question. Please be gentle :))

Comment: please share the UploadFormLayoutImage template. Are you calling the helpers with the arguments in this template?

Comment: @Ankit I have added the template. I actually do not need the helper in the template. I just need to get the same value in the event as in the helper. I will use the value when creating a Mongo-document. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my effort to make the code example easy to read i stripped away the part that caused the problem. I'm using a label for the input field and therefore the input field has an id and thats of course not ok when repeating the template.

I now use the layoutArea-helper as an id value and every thing works just fine.

```
<template name="UploadFormLayoutImage">
    <form class="uploadPanel">
        <input type="file" name="fileupload" id="{{layoutArea}}">
        <label for="{{layoutArea}}">Upload file</label>
    </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you change the `instance.data.layoutArea` in your events method to `this.layoutArea`?

Comment: Unfortunately that generates the same result.

Comment: Hmm. Well, you are setting the `this` value to instance in the events method, and it is being attached to the `input[type="file"]`, which seems to include the first instance `{> UploadFormLayoutImage layoutArea="area1"}}`. To troubleshoot this, you can `console.log` both `e` and `instance` in your events method to see what is coming in. If it is only passing in the data from the first instance, you might try changing your listener to something besides change, like click, as I have found change to be a bit finicky from browser to browser.